# Can not install packages after upgrade to 14.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, 14.10

After upgrade to 14.10 from 14.04 (desktop ed) I can't install new packages or update the existing ones. The system boots but when I do a  `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get some error saying that some packages are not configured.

Here is the console output [output 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B44c6tlSc0inTER1c3c0X0xKNWM/view?usp=sharing) and [output 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B44c6tlSc0inWFROelBhREdubEk/view?usp=sharing)

I looked and I'm still on kernel 3.13.0-37-generic. The upgrade seems to have not worked as intended. Is there some way to restart the upgrade?

Comment: There are bunch of package dependency problems. Can you run `sudo apt-get install -f` and post the output please? The content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem
When i run "sudo apt-get install -f" or "sudo dpkg --configure -a"
the system stuck for an hours at the last line

Here is the output:

```
elinko@Elinko:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing old bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bcmwl
Version: 6.30.223.248+bdcom
Kernel:  3.16.0-23-generic (i686)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

wl.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...........

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.30.223.248+bdcom
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.16.0-23-generic
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.16.0-23-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
```